# How can use isempty function or another function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulation

i didn't know how to use `isempty` function
for example:

the first matrix from simulation is

```
[18 1 0 0 0;12 0 0 0 1;15 1 1 0 0]
```

and the second matrix from simulation is

```
[25 0 0 0 0;30 1 1 0 0;14 0 0 1 0]
```

and the third matrix from simulation is

```
[50 1 0 0 0;12 0 0 1 0;24 1 1 1 0]
```

I used the following function :

```
idxfun=@(x)find(ismember(x(:,2:end),[1 0 0 0],'rows'))

a=the first matrix(idxfun(the first matrix),:)
```

the answer is as follows:`18 1 0 0 0` the second matrix answer is:  `empty matrix:0-by-5` then the simulation stop!  what i want is to make the simulation continue and go to the next matrix and in this example the answer will be `50 1 0 0 0`

Comment: What do you mean by simulation? How are you running the simulation and how is it getting stopped?

Comment: did you try typing help isempty in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

just send the result through the `isempty` function:

```
temp = [25 0 0 0 0;30 1 1 0 0;14 0 0 1 0];
h = idxfun(temp);
if (isempty(h))
    disp('Pattern not found');
else
    disp('Pattern found');
end

temp = [12 0 0 1 0;50 1 0 0 0;24 1 1 1 0];
h = idxfun(temp);
if (isempty(h))
    disp('Pattern not found');
else
    disp('Pattern found');
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use `try` and `catch`

```
 try
    a = result( idxfun( result ), : );
 catch em
    a = [];
    fprintf(1, 'no match found\n');
 end
```